# how to create a new php page with php- apostrophe issue

Tags: php

To be more clear, I do understand how to create a new php file with php, I'm using `fwrite`, like so:

```
//actually create the file now

$my_file=$post_title_edited . ".php";;

$fh= fopen($my_file, 'w');

fwrite($fh, $head);
fwrite($fh, $body);
fwrite($fh, $php);
fwrite($fh, $php2);
fwrite($fh, $php3);
fwrite($fh, $phpend);
fwrite($fh, $end); 
fclose($fh);

//redirect to created file
header("location:". $post_title_edited .".php");
```

Now it all works just fine, or rather it would, if it were not for this issue:

```
$php3='

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    $myusername = $_SESSION['login'];

    echo '  <div id="header-logedin">
              <h3>Hello ' . $myusername . '</h3>
              <a href="login/logout.php">Log out</a>
            </div><!--header-logedin-->
         ';
} else {
    echo $log;
}
```

As you can see, when i begin to set `$php3`, it is interupted by the apostrophe in the login from my first session call. Therefore it can't be set and in turn i can't write it into my new file, also `$php2` has this same problem.

What am i trying to do? In a nutshell: user posts from index.php information posts over onto new page created by this code, after data is checked against sql table to make sure it doesn't already exist, very much like a forum. I really hope this is something complicated and I'm not overlooking something incredibly obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: Heredoc or escaping. Please consult the manual. PHP has a manual. http://php.net/string

Comment: You can use preg_replace() function to escape single quotes, if I haven't misunderstood your question.

Comment: The PHP Code you are also trying to write has errors ??? Really what are your objectives ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do, but you seem to be running into an escaping problem.

To make the apostrophe not actually end the string, you can either:

- Escape it with a slash, like so:

  ```
  $s = 'string with \'single quotes\' inside'
  ```
- Use double quotes inside:

  ```
  $s = 'string with "double quotes" inside'
  ```
- Use a heredoc.

  ```
  $s = <<<END
  This string uses a heredoc. So it doesn't use 'single' or "double" quotes.
  END;
  ```

**edit:**
Also check if you are trying to do something sensible. Ask yourself: do you really need to create a new PHP file? By doing that you are most certainly putting too much complexity on your code, and also weird, nigh undetectable bugs and probably a bunch of security issues as well.